# reversing a for loop in php

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I am very new to PHP. I have this code which outputs an array in reverse order. Although it works Im not sure why especially the $i = $num_items - 1 part of it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
$characters = ['Arthur Dent', 'Ford Prefect', 'Zaphod Beeblebrox', 'Marvin',     'Slartibartfast'];
?>

<ul>
<?php
$num_items = count($characters);
for ($i = $num_items - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    echo "<li>$characters[$i]</li>";
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is going down instead of up. `i$ = number of elements`. You want it to stop at `0` (the first element) and you are subtracting. When in doubt check the actual values: https://eval.in/541945.

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_reverse()` function instead of a `for` loop ;)

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-reverse.php

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, arrays index starts from 0, I'll explain:
Assume that you have 10 items in your array, they are stocked from index 0 to index 9. If you want to iterate through it, you have to start at 9 not 10. which is the number of items -1.

Answer (score 0):

The array in php start from 0 and not 1, if you have array of n items then you can loop through it from 0 to n-1.

Answer (score 0):

Since $i represents the index of the array, $num_items - 1 is because you start at index 0. 
You can use the array_reverse() function and then use a foreach to iterate through the reversed array. You can also check the function asort() in case you would like to arrange the array in alphabetical order.
Hope that helps!!